# Can Raspberry Pi 2 connect to a printer directly via ethernet?

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, server, printing

Can a Raspberry Pi 2 use its ethernet port to connect directly to a printer's ethernet port so it can function as a print server? The Raspberry Pi 2 would have a WiFi dongle.

How can this be accomplished? Any potential problems or performance issues?

Answer (score 1):

This falls into the realm of being technically possible, but not something you're going to find an off the shelf solution for. You would need to somehow virtualize a network in the RPi's OS, and then somehow share that connection to the broader network...

A better solution would be to connect the printer to the RPi through USB and share it in the network that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree that Jacobm001's answer is the simplest solution, but if you're determined to use ethernet you could look at using hostapd to setup an access point through the eth0 interface.

This article explains how to setup hostapd, dnsmasq, and iptables to route the connection. You'll not need to deal with tor or vpn, unless you want to. and make sure you route eth0 as the access point.

http://makezine.com/projects/browse-anonymously-with-a-diy-raspberry-pi-vpntor-router/